# Stop client visiting page that should only be included

Tags: php

`header.php` is always included by other PHP files like `index.php`, `member.php`, etc.

How can I prevent the client from visiting my `header.php`?

Comment: Why do you even care about that? :D.

Comment: use `htaccess` for this

Comment: Just move header.php out of your web root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of `index.php`, add:

```
define('AUTHORISED_TO_INCLUDE', 1);
```

At the top of `header.php`, add:

```
if(!defined('AUTHORISED_TO_INCLUDE')) die();
```

Comment: The drawback is that you have to define the constant in every file.

Comment: Why set `AUTHORIZED_TO_INCLUDE` after you've already determined it's set? Btw, "Z", not "S".

Comment: @Juhana That is correct. Still, you'd have to add each file name into the `.htaccess` anyway, by using that method.

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe I speak English, not American. It is "S".

Comment: No, you only have to add header.php to .htaccess. Or you can put all include files in a single directory and disallow the entire directory.

Comment: Ah, my spell check caught it, didn't even consider "S" could also be correct. But still, why define it after you know it's defined?

Comment: @Juhana Yeah, you only have to add `header.php` if that's the only file to disallow access to. Likewise, you'd only have to add the `if(!defined)` line to `header.php` using this method. Each method requires adding data to.

Comment: @Juhana Good point, I removed that. The logic behind it was to allow including other pages, from the included page. But you're right, it's of course already defined `;)`